# Remove nested array from an object

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to convert

```
const mockResults = [
    [{ user: { firstName: '1', lastName: '1' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '2',lastName: '2' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '3',lastName: '3' }, status: 'CORRECT' }]
];
```

to

```
const mockResults = [
    { user: { firstName: '1', lastName: '1' }, status: 'WRONG' },
    { user: { firstName: '2',lastName: '2' }, status: 'WRONG' },
    { user: { firstName: '3',lastName: '3' }, status: 'CORRECT' }
];
```

The whole task is to transform `mockResults` to `requiredFormat`, that's why I need to remove nested arrays:

```
const requiredFormat = [
  {
    status: 'WRONG',
    data: [{ user: {firstName: '1', lastName: '1'}}, { user: {firstName: '2', lastName: '2'}}],
  },
  {
    status: 'CORRECT',
    data: [{ user: {firstName: '3', lastName: '3'}}],
  },
];
```

Here's what I tried so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/9uLje3sg/

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered using `.map`?

Comment: `mockResults.map(i => i[0])`…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: `let result = mockResults.map(([user]) => user);`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Update the question with a demo

Comment: What? but, you've changed the output, I think

Comment: const result = mockResults.flat().map(item => {
 return {
   status: item.status,
  data: [item.user]
  }
});

what about this? this will produce `requiredFormat`
https://jsfiddle.net/2h617s3x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `map` as follow which returns an array with the desired objects.

```
let result = mockResults.map(([user]) => user);
```

*That approach is assuming there is only one index per array from the original array.*

> According to the approach for `requiredFormat`

You can use the function `reduce` for grouping and the function `Object.values` for getting the desired output.

```js
const mockResults = [
    [{ user: { firstName: '1', lastName: '1' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '2',lastName: '2' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '3',lastName: '3' }, status: 'CORRECT' }]
];

let requiredFormat = Object.values(mockResults.reduce((a, [{user, status}]) => {
  (a[status] || (a[status] = {data: [], status})).data.push(user);
  return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(requiredFormat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Sorry for misunderstanding!

Answer (score 4):

You can use flat method from Array javascript object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

If you want to change the source of data and change the shape of it, using map and reduce methods can help you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

In your precise example reduce would fit as you are creating a new object grouping per status property.

```js
const mockResults = [
    [{ user: { firstName: '1', lastName: '1' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '2',lastName: '2' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '3',lastName: '3' }, status: 'CORRECT' }]
];
const flattedAndReduced = mockResults.flat().reduce( (acc, curr)=>{
  const statusIndex = { 'WRONG' : 0, 'CORRECT': 1 };
  acc[statusIndex[curr.status]].data.push({ user: curr.user} );
  return acc;
}, [
    {
      status: 'WRONG',
      data: [],
    },
    {
      status: 'CORRECT',
      data: [],
    }
  ]
  );
console.log(flattedAndReduced);
```

Comment: The function `flat` adds overhead in this approach.

Comment: That's true, any reiteration over the data source does that. 

Originally the user, just asked about how to "flat" the array and as he kept the question but added a "second step" I updated my original answer too.

Comment: Got it, you kept it that way just to let it know how to use the function `flat`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return the object from first index.

**Please Note:** variable declared with [**`const`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) can not be modified, use *[**`let`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead.

```js
let mockResults = [
    [{ user: { firstName: '1', lastName: '1' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '2',lastName: '2' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '3',lastName: '3' }, status: 'CORRECT' }]
];

mockResults = mockResults.map(i => i[0]);
console.log(mockResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mockResults = [
    [{ user: { firstName: '1', lastName: '1' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '2',lastName: '2' }, status: 'WRONG' }],
    [{ user: { firstName: '3',lastName: '3' }, status: 'CORRECT' }]
];
const requiredFormat = [
  {status: 'WRONG', data: []},
  {status: 'CORRECT', data: []},
];

for(let [{user,status}] of mockResults) {  
  requiredFormat[ status==="WRONG" ? 0 : 1].data.push({user});
}
console.log(requiredFormat);
```